# PHP Twilio App - Including SMS file breaks Foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, twilio

I cant figure this out so I'm hoping you can lend a hand.

I am creating a twilio app, and I'm including this entire file in a foreach loop. But it keeps breaking my loop and wont continue after it runs.

It works great, but the foreach this is included inside of will not continue after it runs.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nick

```
<?php
//shorten the URL
$tinyurl = file_get_contents("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=".$ebay_url);

    // Include the PHP TwilioRest library
    require "twilio/twilio.php";

    // Twilio REST API version
    $ApiVersion = "2010-04-01";

    // Set our AccountSid and AuthToken
    $AccountSid = "removed";
    $AuthToken = "removed";

    // Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new TwilioRestClient($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    // make an associative array of server admins
    $people = array(
        "removed"=>"Nick",
      //"4158675310"=>"Helen",
      //"4158675311"=>"Virgil",
    );

    // Iterate over all our server admins
    foreach ($people as $number => $name) {

        // Send a new outgoinging SMS by POST'ing to the SMS resource */
        // YYY-YYY-YYYY must be a Twilio validated phone number
        $response = $client->request("/$ApiVersion/Accounts/$AccountSid/SMS/Messages",
            "POST", array(
            "To" => $number,
            "From" => 'removed',
            "Body" => 'Alert! '.$title.' found for '. $price. '. View the item here: '.$tinyurl,
        ));
        if($response->IsError)
            echo "Error: {$response->ErrorMessage}\n";
        else
            echo "Sent message to: {$response->ResponseXml->SMSMessage->To}\n";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're doing a require inside the for loop.  There are objects defined in that [twilio library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) so the second time you require it, the classes get defined again and this throws an error.

If you have error_reporting(E_ALL) set then you'll see an exception to that effect in your output.

I would either change it to a require_once or move it out of the for loop.

I hope that helps.